# Role of the discrete subgroups of Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

This is a question I don't believe is too vague to admit a sensible answer:

> In what directions can the structure theory of the discrete subgroups of real and p-adic Lie groups applied? What situations might arise in which one could to delve into the theory of discrete groups to arrive at some other end?

Also,

> Why might a number/representation theorist be interested in results like Ihara's which states that a torsion-free discrete subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is free? (Aside from just the intrinsic interest of the result in a vacuum, which is still very interesting.)

Does the main interest lie in applying strong approximation to understand adelic quotients $G(\mathbb{A})/G(\mathbb{Q})$ (for nice algebaic groups $G$)?

Comment: As a very partial answer, these groups have application to physics.  In fact, there is an entire theory called $p$-adic quantum mehanics, though I know very little about it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for telling me what's up, Doc.

Comment: Please explain the down-vote, which I doubt was due to the bad Bugs Bunny line.

Comment: Hah! I get it.  Btw, I have a theory that "Elmer Fudd" is morphed from "Elmer, PhD", and the person who created Bugs Bunny had a bad college experience with said Professor Elmer.  Thus all the humilating crap that Bugs perpetrated on him.  It also explains the catchphrase, "What's up, Doc?".

Comment: And I agree with Joshua. I hope that was not the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Dear Joshua, That's a pretty expansive question.  Do you know at all about automorphic forms?  Regards,

Comment: @Matt E: regarding the expansiveness, it didn't seem that way when I posted this, but you would certainly know better than I would. Might you then suggest a narrower question, one which might generate some more discussion?

Comment: regarding automorphic forms, I maybe understand some rough, general ideas at best - but no, I'm not really familiar with the subject. However, if you'd be willing to pretend like I am though in an answer, then I would certainly try to familiarise with automorphic forms enough to understand it afterward.